# How to I re-authenticate a jupyter notebook browser session?

Tags: authentication, jupyter-notebook

Sometimes I find that the authentication for my jupyter notebook session has elapsed (typically on my laptop after a long sleep). How can I re-authenticate without closing the notebook in the browser (ie: without losing any edits I may have just made)?

I have tried to re-connect the kernel, but this does not work, and I can't find an option to renew authentication.

This has happened to me when I run a notebook on eg. `localhost:8889` through an ssh tunnel. When the computer sleeps and is disconnected from the internet, the tunnel is broken, and eventually my session with the jupyter server is cancelled/closed.

Answer (score 0):

I found that if I refresh the jupyter "home page" (eg: `http://localhost:8888/tree` when running locally), I get a screen asking for the authentication token. After providing this, I can then re-connect the kernel on any running notebooks.

The token can be found in the logs of the jupyter server. The server will provide the token again if you send it a KBD-INTERRUPT (ctrl-C) then press 'n' (ie: don't stop the server).